Double dagger of footnote overlapping with author affiliation in Springer Nature template
I'm using the Springer Nature Latex Template. The Fourth Author was affiliated with Company 1 while the research was conducted, but no longer works there. I'm not sure what the standard way of indicating this is (recommendations about that are welcome as well), but my idea was to add a footnote with a double dagger symbol next to his name. I tried:

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}


\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\author*[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author*[2]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}

\author[1]{\fnm{Fourth} \sur{Author\footnote[3]{Affiliated with Company 1 at the time the research was conducted}}}\email{ivauthor@gmail.com}

\author[1]{\fnm{Fifth} \sur{Author}}\email{vauthor@gmail.com}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\abstract{Lorem ipsum}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\end{document}



But the dubble dagger symbol overlaps with the superscript 1 from his affiliation. How do I fix this or is there a better way of doing this?


Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code fragment doesn't compile. Please make it (minimally) compilable.

Can you post a MWE, your code doesn't even have \begin{document} and \end{document}.

@Mico My code fragment compiles now.

@Dorian My code compiles now.

This patch adds some space before the double dagger.

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

%********************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@maketitle}
{\renewcommand\thefootnote{\hskip1.0ex\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}
{}{}

\makeatother
%**********************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \title[Article Title]{Article Title}
    
    \author*[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
    \equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
    
    \author*[2]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
    \equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
    
    \author[1]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \author[1]{\fnm{Fourth} \sur{Author\footnote[3]{Affiliated with Company 1 at the time the research was conducted}}}\email{ivauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \author[1]{\fnm{Fifth} \sur{Author}}\email{vauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

    \abstract{Lorem ipsum}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
    
\end{document}

